# DllImport incomplete names

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, portability, dllimport

I am using several P/Invokes under .NET. However, I want my library to work both in Windows and Linux, preferably with the same binaries.

Since the native library I depend on is available on multiple platforms, I was hoping to just have them along with my managed library's binaries.

Right now I'm using something like this:

```
[DllImport("/usr/lib/libMYLIBNAME.so.1")]
```

But this obviously only works for Linux. I was considering that I could possibly copy that binary from /usr/lib and distribute along with my application, so I could reduce the above to:

```
[DllImport("libMYLIBNAME.so")]
```

But this still is Linux-only.

Is there anyway to change the library name string so it'd look for libMYLIBNAME.so under Linux and MYLIBNAME.dll on Windows, or something very similar?

I would like to avoid anything that requires recompilation for each supported platform...

(Note: even better would be a solution that'd look for MYLIBNAME.dll on Windows and /usr/lib/libMYLIBNAME.so.1 on Linux, but this improvement is optional)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things

1- DllImport without the extension
This is supported on Windows, Linux and MAC and will import the appropriate library for the target platform.

```
[DllImport("libMYLIBNAME")] -
```

2- The preffered option is to use the `<dllmap/>` which allows you to map an import library name to the target platform library name. So if on Windows you have a dll called `mylib.dll` and the corresponding Linux so is `mylinuxlib.so.3.6.1` you can import this using the windows DLL name

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll")]
```

And add a configuration to the config to map this name to the Linux library name

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="mylib.dll" target="mylinuxlib.so.3.6.1" />
</configuration>
```

Read more [Here](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)

Comment: I'm going with the dllmap option. I knew about it but I didn't know it could be specified per-assembly.

Comment: @Hans, that is strange, I tested it and it worked for me. Did you have the `.so` in the same directory as the `.exe`? I tested with Mono 2.4.4 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I had a case where leaving off the extension worked in my app, but not in the unit tests. Possibly different code paths (load via current directory vs. app config vs. SetDllDirectory) have different behaviour??

Comment: To help others.  <dllmap> is mono only.  Seems like you can make your own in .NET:  [GitHub - dotnet/.../samples - DllMapDemo](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/DllMapDemo).  It uses System.Runtime.InteropServices using NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver and NativeLibrary.Load.

Comment: For .net standard System.Runtime.InteropServices has a nuget package but it hasn't been updated since 2016 so I was weary of using it.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices/

Answer (score 3):

One solution I've seen is to create an abstract wrapper class around your P/Invokes and to generate the appropriate one based on environment.

```
public abstract class Wrapper
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      WrappedMethod();
   }

   public static Wrapper GetWrapper()
   {
      //TODO: write some method to determine OS
      return IsLinux() ? new LinuxWrapper() : new WindowsWrapper();
   }

   public abstract void WrappedMethod();
}

public class WindowsWrapper : Wrapper
{
  //windows dll imports go here

  public override void WrappedMethod()
  {
      //p/invokes go here
  }
}

public class LinuxWrapper : Wrapper
{
  //linux dll imports go here
  public override void WrappedMethod()
  {
     //p/invokes go here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows isn't picky about the filename extension for a DLL.  Changing them isn't unusual, .ocx for ActiveX controls, .scr for screen savers for example.  But still a regular DLL.  The Windows loader verifies the identity of the file from the content, the PE32 header is what makes it a true DLL.

So just rename your Window version of the .dll to .so.  Change the linker's Output name setting or just rename the file.

Comment: If I rename the Windows DLL to *.so, then I won't be able to ship a Linux version in the same package...

Comment: Not sure what a "package" means.  Another directory jumps to mind.

Comment: I meant the same ZIP file I could distribute my assembly in.