# Calling .so library in .Net

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wrote a small C++ library with an exported method. I compile it into a Dll and the method is called without problems, but I need the program to work on Linux, so I compile the library into a Shared Object using msys2 mingw64, but no matter how I try, I get an exception when calling the method:

> Unable to load shared library 'test.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Of course, I run the program in WSL and specify the active directory to the library folder

```
[DllImport("test.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr VerifyCert();
```

I tried to compile the library without any dependencies, but there was no difference

Comment: From the error message it looks like the problem is not in the calling logic on the C# side, but in the .so itself. Have you tried setting `LD_DEBUG` to see the additional diagnostics? Have you tried calling  your .so from the test C++ code?

Comment: Hm, by the way... Can you please try to replace `test.so` with just a `test` in the `DllImport` + rename `test.so` file to the `libtest.so` on the disk? Related info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711131/dllimport-incomplete-names

Comment: Can you confirm the C++ library you have made has access to its dependencies if it has any?

Comment: @Ninotter I also created empty lib wich just return "Hello world", but have same result

Comment: @Serg i will try use another name. How i can use LD_DEBUG?

Comment: `LD_DEBUG` is an environment variable, so you should be able to set it with `export LD_DEBUG=all` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is supposed to work is by setting the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I could not get it to work (not sure if it does work, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34711). So what I ended up doing was using [NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativelibrary.setdllimportresolver?view=net-8.0) to guide the runtime to the .so file.

```
// setup import resolver during startup
NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), DllImportResolver);
```

Define method **DllImportResolver** like so:

```
private const string _libFile = "myapi.so";
private const string _libName = "myapi";
private static string _libPath = "/mylibs";


private static IntPtr ImportResolver(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath)
{
     if (!libraryName.ToLower().Contains(_libName))
     {
         return IntPtr.Zero;
     }

     if (NativeLibrary.TryLoad(Path.Combine(_libPath, _libFile), out IntPtr libHandle))
     {
         return libHandle;
     }

     return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Whenever the runtime tries to invoke a method with DllImport attribute like this:

```
[DllImport("myapi", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern ErrorCodes MyFunc(uint hToken);
```

It will call your ImportResolver method and you can give it some help.

Comment: This  will probably work, but it looks like a big overkill for the initial task of "just call .so somehow". The way of correction of filenames to follow naming conventions looks much simplier.

Comment: @Serg If you can get it to work: sure. I couldn't. But it's been a while, maybe it is working now.